# Insert into new table from a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have some data in a view which I want to insert into a new table. what's the easiest, cleanest way to do it. I want the data to be inserted in new table as soon as data is inserted in base table on which the view is created. Can I use trigger for this ? which one?

Comment: `Trigger` is the ideal approach..

Comment: even though you go for trigger if it is a single line view we can write insert trigger but if it is dealing with multiple tables we need to write multiple insert triggers

Comment: You can also define the trigger on the view, but then you have to use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql)

Comment: I think INSTEAD OF will not fire on view when insert is done on base table. I tried but it did not inserted any records in new table

Answer (score 1):

Try this it may helps you

```
CREATE TRIGGER yourNewTrigger ON yourSourcetable
FOR INSERT
AS

INSERT INTO yourNewDestinationTable
        (col1, col2    , col3, user_id, user_name)
    SELECT
        'a'  , default , null, user_id, user_name
        FROM inserted

go
```

Comment: Thanks but where will I refer view columns in here.